# extracting last two letters from a list of names by python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list of names with male and female tags to them. I have to extract last two letters of the names and the tag as well. I have shown a sample from the list.

```
([['suzetta', 'f'],
  ['teresita', 'f'],
  ['kaja', 'f'],
  ['nikita', 'm'],
  ['ina', 'f'],
  ['viviene', 'f'],
  ['lancelot', 'm'],
  ['nolan', 'm'],
  ['clayton', 'm'],
  ['almire', 'f'],
  ['ernest', 'm'],
  ['aubert', 'm'],
  ['kelsi', 'f'],
  ['phillipe', 'm'],
  ['lillian', 'f'],
  ['giovanni', 'm'],
  ['rochell', 'f'],
  ['mag', 'f'],
```

The code I am using is :

```
def last(letters):
    A = (i[-2:] for i in letters)
    return A
```

It is not returning the expected output because of the male and female tags in the name. Is there any work around for this? Thanks in advance!!

The expected output should be something like this:

[['ta', 'f'], ['ta', 'f'], ['ja', 'f'], ['ta', 'm'], ['na', 'f']]

Comment: include the expected output in your post.

Comment: How would you process a single item from the list? Given code that processes one item of a list, how do you write a comprehension to apply that to all items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```py
inp = [['suzetta', 'f'], ['teresita', 'f'], ['kaja', 'f'], ['nikita', 'm'], ['ina', 'f']]
output = [[x[0][-2:], x[1]] for x in inp]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
[['ta', 'f'], ['ta', 'f'], ['ja', 'f'], ['ta', 'm'], ['na', 'f']]
```